# how to apply dynamic programming in finding the minimum cost to create the tower in a field

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

you are given an `N X M` rectangular field with bottom left point at the origin. You have to construct a tower with square base in the field. There are trees in the field with associated cost to uproot them. So you have to minimize the number of trees uprooted to minimize the cost of constructing the tower.

**Example Input:**

```
N = 4 
M = 3 
Lenght of side of Tower = 1 
Number of Trees in the field = 4  

1 3 5  
3 3 4  
2 2 1  
2 1 2
```

The 4 rows in the Input are the coordinates of the tree with cost for uprooting as the third integer.

Tree coinciding with the edge of the tower is considered as placed inside the tower and have to be uprooted as well.

I'm facing problem in formulating the Dynamic Programming relation for this problem

thanks

Comment: Do you have bounds on M and N?  How about the size of the tower?

Comment: there are reasonable bounds  mentioned . 2≤N, M ≤ 1000

Comment: What is the cost function? Case A: 10sq tower and 5 tree cost vs Case B: 11sq tower and 6 tree cost. Which one is optimal?

Comment: size of tower is fixed as the length of the side will be given. we only have to minimize the cost of cutting the tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your problem boils down to:  find the KxK subblock of an MxN matrix with the smallest sum.  You can solve this problem efficiently (proportional to the size of your input) by using an integral transform.  Of course, this doesn't necessarily help you with your dynamic programming issue -- I'm not sure this solution is equivalent to any dynamic programming formulation....

At any rate, for each index pair `(a,b)` of your original matrix `M`, compute an "integral transform" matrix `I[a,b] = sum[i<=a, j<=b](M[i,j])`.  This is computable by traversing the matrix in order, referring to the value computed from the previous row/column.  (with a bit of thought, you can also do this efficiently with a sparse matrix)

Then, you can compute the sum of any subblock `(a1..a2, b1..b2)` in constant time as `I[a2,b2] - I[a1-1,b2] - I[a2,b1-1] + I[a1-1,b1-1]`.  Iterating through all KxK subblocks to find the smallest sum will then take time proportional to the size of your original matrix also.

---

Since the original problem is phrased as a list of integral coordinates (and, presumably, expects the tower location to be output as an integral coordinate pair), you likely do need to represent your field as a sparse matrix for an efficient solution -- this involves sorting your trees' coordinates in lexicographic order (e.g. first by `x`-coordinate, then by `y`-coordinate).  Note that this sorting step may take `O(L log L)` for input of size `L`, dominating the following steps, which take only `O(L)` in the size of the input.

Also note that, due to the problem specifying that "trees coinciding with the edge of the tower are uprooted...", a tower with edge length K actually corresponds to an `(K+1)x(K+1)` subblock.

Comment: It can be solved with sub-block solution, but the condition "Tree coinciding with the edge of the tower is considered as placed inside the tower and have to be uprooted as well" makes it slightly complicated.

Comment: I have upvoted, but you need to address that part of the problem as well.

Comment: Isn't that just a boundary condition?  At any rate, I will add a section on the specifics of the original problem.

Comment: No it is not. Consider a 3X3 matrix (indexed from 1-3). To create a square of length 1 at the center (at 2X2) you need to clear the following five squares: (2,2), (2,1), (2,3), (1,2), (3,2). Which means that the sub-solution is not exactly a rectangle.

Comment: What about (1,1), (1,3), (3,3), and (3,1)?  I would not interpret the OQ as specifically excluding the corner cases 8^) -- but if you did want to exclude them, you could track and subtract them in the final pass.

Comment: (1,1) and (2,2) does not share edges.

Comment: thanks, it seems like it will do the job. let me solve it and add my answer soon.